# Outside styles not overriding Shadow DOM styles

Tags: css, polymer, components, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to style the `<app-drawer>` [component](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout) and give it background-color. In its documentation, app-drawer offers a [custom variable available](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/tree/master/app-drawer) to affect the app drawer content container (`#contentContainer`).

```
app-drawer {
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        --app-drawer-content-container: {
            background-color: orange !important;
        };
    }
```

These styles do process but they don't override the [native component styles](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/master/app-drawer/app-drawer.html). 
[Here's what comes up for me in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIBrX.png).

> [Outside styles always win over styles defined in shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#stylefromoutside) - Google Developers

I'm importing the element from the owner document.

```
<!--index.html-->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-layout.html">

<style>
    app-drawer {
        ...
    }
    ...
</style>
<app-drawer-layout>
    <app-drawer slot="drawer">
        <app-toolbar>Main Title</app-toolbar>
    </app-drawer>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

Can anyone figure out what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `box-shadow` inside `--app-drawer-content-container`. This is working for me:

```
app-drawer {
  z-index: 3;
  --app-drawer-content-container: {
    box-shadow: 1px 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Not making a visual difference on my end.

Comment: What does it look like in DevTools? Do you have some element in `app-drawer` that is covering the entire area? Sorry, I've no better idea. As shown above, my background is orange but my button, title, etc use their settings.

Comment: `app-drawer` has its own shadow root element. Inside of there is the `div#scrim` which creates the transparent dark background overlay, the other element `div#contentContainer` holds the content. I can inline-style `#contentContainer` and the background color changes. 
I've also tried various combinations of selectors, e.g: `app-drawer #contentContainer { ...styles here }`

Comment: I'm seeing the same stuff in the `shadow-root` of the v2 `polymer-starter-kit`. Not in the `shadow-root` but children of the `app-drawer` itself, there are an `app-toolbar` and an `iron-selector`. Just adding your CSS to the template style in `my-app.html`, the `app-drawer`'s background is orange. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks, @Thad. I got it to work using your code. On inspection of my original code, I wasn't defining my custom element with the Polymer spec, i.e `class MyClass extends Polymer.Element {}`. I was using the method outlined in the original spec: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements. I believe this may have interfered somehow.